# How to build a dataframe from scratch?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a Dataframe from a dict:

```
frio = {'Frio11' : frioMurteira11.FrioAcum, 'Frio12' : frioMurteira12.FrioAcum,\
    'Frio13' : frioMurteira13.FrioAcum}
```

and creating a range to use as a index

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/11/2011', periods=107, freq ='D')
```

then, when I try to create the DataFrame

```
DataFrame(frio, index=rng)
```

I got the following error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3,), indices imply (3, 107)
```

Could you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Can you tell what is the dictionary you have specified? Also error is coming because the length of index is 107 and I am guessing 'Frio11','Frio12','Frio13' don't have same length

Comment: When I type frio, python returns [107 rows x 1 columns] for each of the elements

Comment: Well I am not able to run frio = {'Frio11' : frioMurteira11.FrioAcum, 'Frio12' : frioMurteira12.FrioAcum,\
    'Frio13' : frioMurteira13.FrioAcum} successfully.Its giving me an error

Comment: This means that `FrioAcum` is not iterable, it is viewing it as a single value, it needs to be a list or other iterable object in order for the shapes to align, what exactly is `FrioAcum`?

Comment: FrioAcum is a column of a DataFrame with 107 elements

Comment: So it's a Pandas series is what you are saying, this should work and it works for me on Pandas version 0.13.1, what version are you using? You can print `pd.version.version`

Comment: @Hugo could you post some sample data and code that shows this failing

Comment: Can I send you the notebook and the csv that I am using?

Comment: What is frioMurteira13.FrioAcum

Comment: FrioAcum is a column of a DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(frio, index=rng)
```